# VS Code Integrated Terminal Doesn't Display Compound Emoji, but System Terminal Does

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh, emoji

When typing or printing compound emojis in the VS Code integrated terminal, either those using a ZWJ (zero-width join) or the compound national flag emoji, I cannot get the actual emoji to print. For example, if I write the command

`echo ‍♀️`

This displays as

`echo "<0001f9d4><200d>♀️"`

And then prints as

`‍ ♀️` (spaces added, as pasting the entire entity just prints the actual emoji on this platform)

This persists even if I add a fallback emoji font to the integrated terminal's font list. However, if I do the same on the default MacOS Terminal app, the command displays as follows:
`echo "<0001f9d4><200d>♀️"`

So, still the same, but prints as:

`‍♀️`

What I can't understand is why the integrated terminal would somehow be divorced from the default MacOS one. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Edit: Here is the output of `Help: About` on VS Code:

```
Version: 1.84.0 (Universal)
Commit: d037ac076cee195194f93ce6fe2bdfe2969cc82d
Date: 2023-11-01T11:30:19.406Z (4 days ago)
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.4.0
```

I have only tested this on my current OS, MacOS Monterey 12.3.1. This issue occurs with both zsh and bash.

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Does this happen for all your shells / terminal profiles? What OS are you on? What OSes have you tested? I can reproduce on Ubuntu 22.04.2 with VS Code 1.84.0 and Bash terminal profile.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the idea of _compound emoji_, but do they have a unicode codepoint? If they don't have, I don't see how zsh could display them properly.

Comment: Of course a Terminal application, which has the purpose of **rendering** the output of the process which runs in it, can take individual characters and render/display them as a new character. If one such application does it like this (like VScode terminal), you can not conclude that all terminal applications do it.

Comment: Emoji are Unicode-compliant, but the problem is that some actually have multiple Unicode codepoints. For example, the standard "man" emoji is just one codepoint, but "white woman with beard" is 5: man with bread, zero-width join (ZWJ), white race indicator, ZWJ, female indicator. What strikes me as strange is that even when I use the same underlying terminal emulator for both VS Code and Mac, I receive different results, and was hoping that maybe I just needed to adjust some VS Code settings.

Comment: they are not the same underlying terminal emulators (VS Code uses xterm.js), and terminal emulation might not be the only thing at play here. It could be a matter of input parsing and processing / clipboard handling. The issue in VS Code could theoretically happen at one of several levels or a procedural combination of several layers: VS Code, Electron, Chromium, or xterm.js.

Comment: Gotcha, that does make sense, thanks for the insight